# Webpack generate different chunks with the same contenthash

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

I've a Webpack 4.1 configuration that use code splitting and output chunks names using a pattern like `myproj-[name]-[contenthash].chunk.js`.

I'm copying all of the production bundle files, for every version, in the same directory on the server, being sure (until now) that chunks are unique and I have no clashing.

Today I found an issue releasing a new version of the application: I've a file named `myproj-modulex-0bb2f31cc0ca424a07d8.chunk.js` that was also generated with the old version (that's the scope of contenthash, isn't it?). I'm expecting that the content of the file is identical but **it isn't**.

There's only one character changed (the array index). The chunk start with...

```
(window.webpackJsonp_XXXX=window.webpackJsonp_XXXX||[]).push([[7],{"2d0274e27fde9220edd9"...
```

...while the old version was using `...push([[6],...`.

One of the difference of the new version from the old ones is that I added new code splitting points.

So: it seems that new split points changed chunks order, but webpack still use the same generated filename (probably because `contenthash` is referred to the real module content?).

The issue is critical: when the new file is copied on the server it overwrite the old file and so client using old version are not working anymore because chunk is loaded in a wrong position on the push array (I guess).

Error is:

```
"Error: Loading chunk 6 failed.
(missing: https://.../myproj-xxx-0bb2f31cc0ca424a07d8.chunk.js)"
```

There's a way to fix this issue, maybe naming pushed chunks, or specifying the order, or generated different hashes? `chunkhash` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack uses ids as a chunk references and those ids are not guaranteed to remain the same for the same chunks among different builds. `contenthash` is used for files extracted by `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin`. The same source content will get the same `contenthash` but the generated file may differ due to `id` changes.

Try using `myproj-[name]-[chunkhash].chunk.js` instead.

Also take a look at [optimization.moduleIds](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationmoduleids) and `optimization.chunkIds` settings.

Comment: Thanks, those information point me to the right solution.

Seems that `chunkIds` (not `moduleIds`) was the answer.
One time again: I'm stuck by the edge cases on webpack... Web is full of tutorial just saying "just use contenthash" while the solution is not that easy.